# Feature queries in sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently working on a project which uses grid for layout purposes. Grid working fine in newer browsers but support has to be provided for the older browsers as well. So I came across this article by [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/CSS_Grid_and_Progressive_Enhancement) which encouraged the use of feature queries in order to make use of CSS grid in newer browsers and resort to standard CSS for older browsers in my case.

So here is where my problem lies. When I use @supports feature query, I get below error:

[image]

Am I using it in some wrong way?

Comment: Image is great but if you give us a [text code example](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) of the `.content` block we can more directly answer your issue.

Comment: What version of SASS are you using? Please also check whether your IDE uses the same version.

Comment: when gulp convert your sass to css, did the buiding process finish or you get error  and the building process stop?

Comment: I think its the IDE's problem only. Code is compiling and running fine on all browsers with feature query implemented.

Comment: @AakashThakur See my answer. It's 100% an issue with VS, and has been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug with Visual Studio Code. Update to version 1.19 and the problem is resolved.

[Here's the relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35887), with [fixing commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/commit/61e46981f5aa4f910a69ad1da8a95f78817fb028) for the curious.

Comment: Awesome! I ran into the same issue a few days ago and it worked for me as well, hence the simple answer.